# Multiple “from:” keywords in Outlook advanced search

Tags: outlook, outlook-2013

Re: Desktop client

I've tried this every way I can think of. Scenario: you have an inbox with five emails, each from a different person: personA, personB, ... personE. My goal is to write a search query that excludes people and shows the remaining emails.

I can write positive queries like from:personA OR from:personB, and the query returns a mixed bag of emails from personA and personB.

I've written the converse query NOT (from:personA OR from:personB) and the query returns all emails including personA and personB. I've tried variants like NOT from:personA AND NOT from:personB, NOT from:personA OR NOT from:personB and nothing works.

If I reduce the query to exclude only one person, it works as expected. However, if I try to expand scope to exclude more than one it doesn't returned desired results. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the search box above the Inbox switch to Advanced Find.

http://www.oit.uci.edu/exchange/email/using-advanced-find.php

Select the Advanced Tab, filter by From does not contain. Enter any number of names or name fragments separated by a space.